# How do I enable the SFTP Subsystem in Redhat 5.2 Enterprise Linux?

Tags: ssh, redhat

SSHD works fine but how do I enable the SFTP Subsystem in Redhat 5.2 Enterprise Linux?  It seems to have a older version of SSHD that doesn't support some of the usual directives like Match or ChrootDirectory .  So,  does anyone have an example of how to do this on Redhat 5.2 (or CentOS 5.2?) ??

The file */usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server*  is permissions 755.

I tried both of these in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

But neither of them work.  My psftp says:

```
psftp> open 000.000.00.00
login as: root
root@000.000.00.00's password:
bash: line 2: exec: sftp-server: not found
Fatal: unable to initialise SFTP: could not connect
psftp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SSH is most likely version 4.2, all that SFTP stuff is in version 4.9 from what I can tell. You will need to compile a newer version. The 5.2 RHEL server here is showing 4.2 for the OpenSSH version.

Comment: Do you think if I enable the "redhat network" repository, that the redhat network rpm repository would have a 5.x version of sshd to upgrade to?

Comment: If you mean the default RHEL repos, then I would say no. From some of the build instructions I have seen, I looked like there was new PAM libs required and such. Also my 4.2 version came from the default RHEL repos.

Comment: Here is the build instructions I saw: http://binblog.info/2009/02/27/packaging-openssh-on-centos/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run OpenSSL version 5.*+. The version in the repository for CentOS 5.2 does not support chrootdirectory, etc. I had to compile it from source, but there may be an RPM out there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, thats a great thought "to try a CentOS version".  Maybe I might resort to doing that.

Comment: You will probably need to look beyond the RHEL or CentOS repositories. They will both have the 4.2 version.